# Rails database table relational issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application. The problem is database relation I am trying to make relation within two tables and the same procedure are working properly in another relation but here it's showing an error.

The error is:

> undefined method `create_applied_jobs' for nil:NilClass

Here are my codes:

**applied_job.rb**

```
class AppliedJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :jobseekers
end
```

**jobseeker.rb**

```
class Jobseeker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :applied_job
end
```

**view_details_controller.rb**

```
def create
   params.permit!
   if @applied_job = @current_user.create_applied_jobs(params[:applied_job])
     flash[:notice] = "You have applied successfully"
     render "viewDetails"
   else
     render "viewDetails"
     flash[:warning] = "Please try agian"
   end
 end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
 def current_user
   @current_user ||= Jobseeker.find_by(jobseeker_id: session[:user_id])
 end
```

**viewDetails.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for :applied_job, url: viewDetails_path(@applied_job), action: :create, method: :post  do |f| %>
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li><label>Preferred Joining Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <%= f.text_field :preffered_joining_date, class: 'field-long', id: 'datepicker', placeholder: 'Preferred Joining Date'%>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Expected Salary <span class="required">*</span></label>
             <%= f.text_field :expected_salary, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Expected Salary'%>
        </li>
        <li>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
 <% end %>
```

I want to insert data to applied_jobs table where jobseeker_id is foreign_key.

Anyone can help me please to identify where the bug?

Comment: Mukto Mona, what is current_user, is it user table, post user.rb code as well

Comment: Okay @RameshKumarThiyagarajan

Comment: Do you have `jobseeker_id` in `jobseekers` table?

Comment: Also try `current_user.create_applied_jobs(params[:applied_job])` instead of `@current_user.create_applied_jobs(params[:applied_job])`

Comment: Yes, I have jobseekers table also tried your suggestion, but issue is still as before @Pavan

Comment: I'm asking do you have `jobseeker_id` column in `jonseekers` table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101450/discussion-between-mukto-mona-and-pavan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app/controllers/view_details_controller.rb
class ViewDetailsController < ApplicationController

    def create
       @applied_job = current_user.applied_jobs.new applied_params
       if @applied_job.save
         flash[:notice] = "You have applied successfully"
       else
         flash[:warning] = "Please try agian"
       end
       render "viewDetails"
     end

     private

     def applied_params
        params.require(:applied_job).permit(:params, :for, :job)
     end
end
```

When calling a method, you'll have to make sure you're referencing the method name itself (in your case `current_user`). Although it sets an [*instance* variable](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables), the call should go to the method itself (as it will return the value set by the var).

---

Since you're a beginner, here are some pointers based on your code:

-

**Read up on [MVC (Model View Controller)](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/)** -- your controller should be a conduit for your model. The naming convention for Rails controllers is to reflect the [*resource*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) that you're trying to manipulate / edit.

Calling your controller `view_details_controller`, and yet you're changing `applied_jobs` goes against the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration). Whilst not a problem, it will cause issues when you start working on larger-scale apps.

To clean it up, do something like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jobs do # -> url.com/jobs/:id
   resources :applications, path: "apply" only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/jobs/:job_id/apply
end

#app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :current_user

   def create
      @job         = Job.find params[:job_id]
      @applied_job = current_user.applied_jobs << @job
   end

   private

   def current_user
      @current_user ||= JobSeeker.find_by jobseeker_id: session[:user_id]
   end
end
```

-

**Use Join tables** -- you're currently creating new `AppliedJob` records each time you send the request to your controller. Whilst it's not my problem how you design your app, what *is* important is that you're making it efficient ([`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

You'd be much more efficient using a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association:

```
#app/models/job_seeker.rb
class JobSeeker < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :applications
   has_many :applied_jobs, through: :applications, class_name: "Job", source: :job
end

#app/models/application.rb
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :job_seeker
   belongs_to :job
end

#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :applications
   has_many :applicants, through: :applications, class_name: "JobSeeker", source: :job_seeker
end
```

The above will allow you to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jobs do
   resources :applications, only: [:create, :destroy] #-> url.com/jobs/:job_id/applications
end

#app/controllers/applications_controller.rb
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @job         = Job.find params[:job_id]
      @application = current_user.applied_jobs << @job #-> automatically creates "application" join record
   end

   def destroy
      @job         = Job.find params[:job_id]
      @application = current_user.applied_jobs.delete @job
   end
end
```

Comment: Now relation is OK, but data are not inserting other columns @Rich Peck

Comment: Can you be specific? Which columns and what data? Did you put in your params into `applied_params` or just used my placeholder code?

Comment: Thanks - when I added `     def applied_params
        params.require(:applied_job).permit(:params, :for, :job)
     end` - can you post your equivalent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101512/discussion-between-mukto-mona-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 0):

Your Jobseeker has

has_one :applied_job

that will add a `create_applied_job` (no s at the end) method to the Jobseeker model, not create_applied_jobs

As for why your current_user is returning null, Normally a Jobseeker table would have an id column, not a jobseeker_id column so I would assume it should be

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= Jobseeker.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

Comment: This is not the current problem. The problem is `@current_user` is nil.